# kubernetes volume mount issue for google PD (kubeadm installed)

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I have Kubernetes installed via kubeadm in google cloud. Trying to mount google PD.

**storageclass.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  fstype: ext4
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

**pvc-claim.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
  storageClassName: standard
```

but getting the following error:

> error while running "VolumeBinding" prebind plugin for pod "test-pd": Failed to bind volumes: provisioning failed for PVC

Answer (score 0):

Upon testing on a GKE cluster I was able to successfully deploy your StorageClass, PersistentVolumeClaim and a deployment of one Pod using it.

To discard the possibility of this being specific to vanilla Kubernetes it might help to also provide the YAML for your `test-pd` Pod/Deployment.